# Exception Enabling Service FILESTREAM - COMException

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, wmi, filestream

This code is supposed to enable FILESTREAM on a SQL Service. There is a manual process to do this, but we really need an automated way. I found this code on another help site. People have been able to get it to work but I am receiving the error below.

A first chance exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in System.Management.dll

```
 private void EnableFilestream(int accessLevel)
        {
            ManagementObject filestreamSettingsObject = GetFilestreamManagementObject("WIN-D0RFC79OHJ7", "MSSQLSERVER");
            ManagementBaseObject methodArgs = filestreamSettingsObject.GetMethodParameters("EnableFilestream");
            methodArgs["AccessLevel"] = accessLevel;
            methodArgs["ShareName"] = ""; //default

            ManagementBaseObject returnObject = filestreamSettingsObject.InvokeMethod("EnableFilestream", methodArgs, null);

            uint returnValue = (uint)returnObject.GetPropertyValue("ReturnValue");

            const uint errorSuccessRestartRequired = 0x80070BC3;
            if (returnValue != 0 && returnValue != errorSuccessRestartRequired)
            {
                Win32Exception win32Exception = new Win32Exception((int)returnValue);
                string exceptionText =
                        string.Format("'EnableFilestream' method returned {0}: {1}", returnValue, win32Exception.Message);
            }
        }




private ManagementObject GetFilestreamManagementObject(string machineName, string instanceName)
        {
            string managementPath = string.Format(@"\\{0}\root\Microsoft\SqlServer\ComputerManagement10", machineName);
            ManagementScope managementScope = new ManagementScope(managementPath);
            managementScope.Connect();

            SelectQuery query = new SelectQuery("FilestreamSettings", string.Format("InstanceName='{0}'", instanceName));
            using (ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(managementScope, query))
            {
                ManagementObjectCollection moc = searcher.Get();
                if (1 != moc.Count)
                {
                    string exceptionText = String.Format("Expected single instance of FilestreamSettings WMI object, found {0}.", moc.Count);
                }
                ManagementObjectCollection.ManagementObjectEnumerator enumerator = moc.GetEnumerator();

                return (ManagementObject)enumerator.Current;
            }
        }
```

I believe the issue is occurring on line:

```
  ManagementObjectCollection moc = searcher.Get();
```

I cannot be fully sure though since it does not actually crash the application. Adding this exception in the debug properties also did not cause it to "break." I am also running this as administrator. Any help is appreciated. If you need anymore information, please let me know.

Comment: Any hresult or error code?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I changed the question to say exception. It doesn't actually crash, the program just doesn't work because it skips over the code after that exception.